# Offline Mode - Updating data once internet is connected

Tags: php, web-services, cookies, websocket, offline-mode

I am just looking for advice on the feasibility of implementing this and any general ideas and  suggestions on whether this is possible. NOT code and this is not homework.

I'm developing an online application for fitness, and, to and from the gym I usually have no internet connection and therefore have to wait until I return home / have internet connection before I can enter all the data for that particular day and any notes.

I'm wondering whether or not it would be possible to somehow develop an offline mode where I can still enter the data and then when I return home, and, connect my laptop to the internet the data will then be uploaded to the server so I don't have to re-enter the data when I get home?

**Thoughts**

My general thoughts would be to place the data inside a cookie, but, I'm not quite sure how the cookie will update itself once the internet has come back.

Another thought would be to use sockets, and, then interact that way. In that, my web-server has a cron job that "Seeks" whether data is available from a particular IP on the network (Again, the server will be on the same network) and if there is, then, the system will transfer the data from my local machine to the web server.

Any ideas of your own will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Save it to a csv, then process the csv when your connected.

Comment: @phpisuber01 Good idea! But, my only concern is this: When I enter "www.mysite.com/fitness/" it will automatically display "cannot connect to the internet" so therefore, will I need to create an "offline" version of the application?

Comment: WAMP, MAMP, XAMP, AMPPS are all LAMP (minus L) stacks that work without an internet connection.

Comment: @phpisuber01 Thank you :) Gotcha! Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it? Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a web application offline by using your computer as a server, you can get PHP stacks like the ones listed below that run apache, php and mysql.

- **Windows:** WAMP, AMPPS
- **Mac:** XAMP, MAMP

Then, you can save all your important data to a CSV file, and once your online your script can push the CSV data to your remote web server.

You can check if your online by pinging google or something.